# PHP & Javascript Toastr

Tags: javascript, php, toastr

Is there a way to show or display JS toastr alerts trought PHP code. This is the code and the alert message.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>_toastr('Your email is not registered, please check.');</script>";
```

Comment: Why is it failing? Are there any JS errors displayed in the console? We can't really help you seeing just that line of code.

Comment: The code is failing because ist not able to load the js files. This is the error in my console: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: _toastr is not defined

Comment: Well then make sure that the JS files are included before making the function call?

Comment: I am not sure if about `_toastr()` but normally i would use it like this `toastr.error('Your email is not registered, please check.')`

Answer (score 2):

Should be no problem because PHP is server-side and you can prepare your toastr e.g. with a session and then put the PHP result in the script-tag.
Just generate a PHP-Session-Array where the error is thrown:

```
<?php
session_start()
$_SESSION['toastr'] = array(
    'type'      => 'error', // or 'success' or 'info' or 'warning'
    'message' => 'error message here!',
    'title'     => 'title here!'
);
?>
```

Now you can fill the script-Tag on the page where the toastr should display:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        <?php
        // toastr output & session reset
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['toastr']))
        {
            echo 'toastr.'.$_SESSION['toastr']['type'].'("'.$_SESSION['toastr']['message'].'", "'.$_SESSION['toastr']['title'].'")';
            unset($_SESSION['toastr']);
        }
        ?>          
    });
</script>
```

Always make sure to load jquery before!